# Inverting a sum of identity and a singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I wish to invert $\mathbf{A}=(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X})$, where $\mathbf{I}$ is the an identity $N\times N$ matrix and $\mathbf{X}$ is an $N \times N$ non-invertible matrix. One way to do it is by using the Newman series expansion, but in my application, it is not converging to the exact solution even when the order of the approximation is very high. I have also tried to do eigen-decomposition, i.e. letting $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{I} -
 \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{Q}^{-1}=\mathbf{Q}(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{D})\mathbf{Q}^{-1}$, then after all $\mathbf{X}$ is singular.  Is there any way to invert $\mathbf{A}$ exactly without having to invert the whole $(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X})$ or $\mathbf{X}$?

Thanks,

_L

Comment: $A$ *is* $(I - X)$, so no, you cannot invert $A$ exactly without inverting $I - X$. To invert one is to invert the other.

Comment: Why are you wanting to invert this matrix? Most things that could be solved with inversion can be solved by other easier methods.

Comment: Easier in terms of complexity? If so, How much gain do these easier methods offer, compared with the well known matrix inversion complexity that is of the order of $N^3$?

Comment: @L.Smash It depends on what you're trying to do... As I asked, why do you need to invert this matrix?

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a few methods of calculating the inverse without directly calculating the inverse of $A$, but I can't really speak to their efficacy.

**Singular Value or Eigenvalue Decomposition:**

SVD tells us that $A=USV^T$ where $U,V$ are orthogonal and $S$ is diagonal. It follows that $A^{-1}=VS^{-1}U^T$. Note that the elements of $S^{-1}$ are simply the reciprocal of the elements of $S$. Eigenvalue decomposition is similar but requires a full set of eigenvalues.

**Series Expansion**

If we treat $I-X$ as a matrix function, we can expand it's inverse into a taylor series. Note that this requires that $|\lambda|<1$ for all eigenvalues of $I-X$ for convergence:

$$(I-X)^{-1}=I+X+X^2+X^3+...$$

This is an approximation however, and has a pretty strict requirement on the eigenvalues.

**Don't Invert it**

Many applications that require matrix inversion can be solved by other means such as LU or SVD decomposition. It really depends on why you need to invert this matrix.